# Column mapper in linq2db is not working the same as in EF Column mapping

Tags: linq-to-sql, mapping, automapper, linq2db

This entity/Poco was working fine with EF:

```
[Column(Name="myFieldNameOnDB")]
public string MyPropNameOnClass{ get; set; }
```

After replacing EF in the entire solution with Linq2DB, it is working where poco class properties are the same as column/field name, but for some classes, there are some properties that are different than a column in name, that was working with specifying a different name in EF with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but I wonder why not working with LinqToDB.Mapping instead of EF and annotation?

I got the below error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid column name myFieldNameOnDB

Any help?

Update:
My class refer to a SQL View

Comment: Do you want to work with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` or linq2db mapping is also enough? Linq2db has it's own `LinqToDB.Mapping.ColumnAttribute`.

Comment: Hey @SvyatoslavDanyliv  , for the mentioned exception occurs when using ColumnAttribute of LinqToDB, it was working with DataAnnotations with EF, but I no longer use EF, therefore I went with Ling2DB and LinqToDB.Mapping.ColumnAttribute, and that caused the issue

Comment: Well it needs investigation. It is common technique and it works very well in many cases. Please create issue with small reproducible steps in github. Anyway, if you defined IMetadataReader - it can be a problem.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv Is it work with Views? I updated the question

Comment: For linq2db there is no differences between tables and views. Do you have IMetadaReader defined? How you migrated to linq2db?